# Converting a simple function from jS to PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have a simple function hash function in JS that I'm struggeling with converting into PHP (for server side validation), it is a simple math function, and I'm not a PHP expert, could any of you shed some light into why I can't have **($variable)(function)** in PHP next to each other?

Here is the function in jS:

```
function claculate(a,b){
    var g=function(a){
      return Math.round(a/Math.pow(10,Math.round(Math.LOG10E*Math.log(a)))*10)
    };
    var f=function(a){
        var h=function(b){
            return b(a)
        };
        var j=function(b){
            return g(a)
        }; 
        return a<b?j:h
     };
     var o=((f(a)(g)%2)||(f(a*b)(g)%7*1/7)||11)^f(b)(g);
     return another_function(a,o);  
}
```

And here is my version in PHP, but there is an error on the $o line, and I'm not sure why ...

```
function claculate($a, $b){
   $g = function ($r){
       return round($r / pow(10, round(M_LOG10E * log($r))) * 10);
   };
   $f = function ($a) use (&$a, &$b, &$g) {
       $h = function ($b) use (&$b, &$a) {
           return $b($a);
        };
        $j = function ($b) use (&$b, &$g, &$a) {
           return $g($a);
        };
        return ($a < $b) ? $j : $h;
    };
    // $o throws error
    $o = $f($a)($g) % 2 || $f($a * $b)($g) % 7 * 1 / 7 || 11 ^ $f($b)($g);
    return another_function($a, $o);
}
```

Any thoughts or right direction is more than welcomed! Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide the output of the error?

Comment: That's the thing, the page loads balnk ... (even with error_reporting on) that's why I'm asking here for help

Comment: You can see the error here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/w3AWi1

Comment: Part of the problem is that I don't know why I cant use the $o variable like this, PHP is not my domain and I'm not able to convert the JS function to PHP for that excact reason

Comment: One thing I can see is that in PHP the `||` is a boolean operation, will always return true or false. In Javascript it will return the value of the operation on either side. While this isn't the issue, breaking up the last long statement will likely fix the issue/error. Example: `var_dump( 5 || 0)` shows `true` as the result while JS would return `5`.

Comment: Oh ok, @JonathanKuhn hmm I will try to recreate the function with that in mind, but so far I'm failing

Comment: Why not use a hash function built into PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, this works the same:

```
function g($r)
{
  return round($r / pow(10, round(M_LOG10E * log($r))) * 10);
}

function claculate($a, $b)
{
  $o = ((g($a) % 2) || (g($a * $b) % 7 * 1 / 7) || 11) ^ g($b);
}
```

The first problem is in difference when evaluating OR statement. (JS returns number, PHP bool.) But this can be solved by using of some conditions.

The worst is that JS uses 2 more digits for real numbers.

Comment: Thanks Jirka, that is excactly what I needed, thanks, you are the PHP guru I neede. Yes, it seems the number return in my server side validation is shorther then the one in JS, but I will probably floor that. Thanks a ton!